# How to debug win implementing a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning

For example, when I implement a svm and it doesn't work well. The problem is I made a wrong choice of alpha when implementing smo algorithm or I got the KKT function wrong. But how can I know what the problem is?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the help documents before posting.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic applies here.  "How to debug" is one of the classic questions *not* to ask here.

Answer (score -1):

In general, cross - validation is used to make sure that your model performs correctly.

Comment: This is more of a comment, not a full answer.